# Getting user input during a .pkg installation process

Tags: macos, pkgbuild

I am working on an installer that will install a program that is designed to be used offline. I am using the repo [from this medium post](https://medium.com/swlh/the-easiest-way-to-build-macos-installer-for-your-application-34a11dd08744) It uses the buildproduct command under the hood. During the installation process I want to prompt the user for either an activation key or a login to verify that they have purchased this software. How can I get user input during the PKG installation process and have that input be processed with the pre-install scripts?

Anyone have any ideas?

I have tried embedding javascript in the welcome.html file (feels dirty just saying it) but javascript is not enabled for the HTML renderer in the welcome screen. (no surprise there)